# VSCode: Run Code Doesn't take virtualenv into consideration

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, virtualenv

**vscode**: 1.31.1
**python extension**: 2019.1.0

Selected Python Interpreter: (proper pyenv environment), it's displayed at the footer.

However when I open a simple test script

```
from apps.business.periods import PeriodFactory
import sys


def init(config='config.settings.local'):
    import os
    import django

    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", config)
    django.setup()


init()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    from apps.business.metrics.data import get_metric
    from apps.business.metrics.widgets import get_widget

    period = PeriodFactory.current_month()
    print(period)
    print(sys.prefix)
    print(sys.executable)
```

and run it (right mouse click - **Run Code**), I get errors:

```
[Running] python -u "/home/dmitry/Projects/analytics/backend/test.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dmitry/Projects/analytics/backend/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from apps.business.periods import PeriodFactory
  File "/home/dmitry/Projects/analytics/backend/apps/business/periods.py", line 43
    range_entries: PeriodOrPeriodTupleList
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

And if I remove the imports

```
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':

    print(sys.prefix)
    print(sys.executable)
```

I get the following output

```
[Running] python -u "/home/dmitry/Projects/analytics/backend/test.py"
/usr
/usr/bin/python
```

If I run the same script from the shell, everything is OK

```
(cam) 
➜ BACKEND_ENVIRONMENT=local python test.py
2019-02 (Feb)
/home/dmitry/.pyenv/versions/cam
/home/dmitry/.pyenv/versions/cam/bin/python
(cam)
```

Comment: I don't have the option `Run Code` on my Vscode with the Python extension installed